# trying to make a function in a object class that divides text file to parts (Java)

Tags: java, file, text, directory

I am trying to divide a text file to 150 parts, so I made a function in the object class itself.
This is the full object class :

```
public TehilimEpisode(int EpisodeID, String[] ab)
{
    this.EpisodeID=EpisodeID;
    this.Perek=ab;
}
public static void setperek(TehilimEpisode[] pirkoni) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\\\*.txt"));
    String nextLine; String[] ab;
        while ((nextLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
        {   
        for(int i=1; i<=150;i++)
        {
            ab = nextLine.split("$");
            pirkoni[i] = new TehilimEpisode(i, ab);
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=150; i++)
        pirkoni.toString();
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(EpisodeID + " & " + Arrays.toString(Perek));
}
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.clone();
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.equals(obj);
}
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finalize();
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.hashCode();
}
}
```

The function name is **setperek**. when I am trying to run the function from the main class, it is writing this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at TehilimEpisode.setperek(TehilimEpisode.java:25)
    at main.main(main.java:48)
```

Comment: Make sure scanner has next line with `i<=150 && scanner.hasNextLine()` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the whole txt in single string then split it by "$".Here is the example in which I use delimiter `\\z` that read the whole file in single string and then I split the string by "$".In below example we read the whole book in single line then split it into episode by "$" as you added  in your book at the end of episode.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReadingWithScanner {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("D:\\book.txt");
    String book = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    /* Using this delimiter you will be able to read whole file in single line. */
    sc.useDelimiter("\\Z");
    book = sc.next();
    String[] episodeArr = book.split("$");
    //Do whatever you want.
  }
}
```

**Update**

`String.split()` takes in regex as argument and $ is a metacharacter in Java regex API. Therefore, you need to escape it:
Use this `book.split("\\$");`

Comment: Thanks but I tried and it hasn't worked... this is the code I wrote: ` public class main { public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { File file = new File("C:\\\\\\\*.txt"); String book = ""; Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); sc.useDelimiter("\\Z"); String[] episodeArr = new String[151]; for(int i=1;i<=150;i++) book = sc.next(); episodeArr[i] = book.split("$"); } }` 
How can I fix that, to divide that to 150 different episodes by the char $ between every episode? I mean, when I try to slice every episode it is just print all the text file in the first place of the array.

Comment: First thing, you don't have to create an array of 150 episode.Second thing is your `book.txt` file contain 150 episode separated by $ so you don't need to run `for` loop for iterating episode.The `String book` contain your whole book and `episodeArr` contain the all episode that you have in your book.And one more thing `split()` function return an array

Comment: Now I can see something :) but this is not splitting my text file to parts, it just put the whole book in the first place of the episodeArr. I mean that when I try to print the second place or any other place which is not the first one, I will get the error "ArrayOutOfBounds" :
`System.out.println(episodeArr[2]);`
*:*
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at main.main(main.java:18)`

Comment: @Aviatar S Actually `split()` function break your string into array if every episode is separated by $. You check that  in your file episode separated by $. And `it just put the whole book in the first place of the episodeArr` also check the output  is it contain $.

Comment: Yes, the output contains $ between any episode, it seems to me that the program is not recognizing the `$` as a `$`.
The file looks like :
`Hello
World
$
I'm
Going
$
To
Show
$
you
Today
$`
Maybe, I'm needed to write the split char different? because the $ is in a new line after every episode...

Comment: @Aviatar S I update the answer which the solves the problem related to `$`. Please mark the answer as accepted if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to below, here i change scanner.nextLine() method to nextLine String.

```
while ((nextLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
    {   
    for(int i=1; i<=150;i++)
    {
        ab = nextLine.split("$");
        pirkoni[i] = new TehilimEpisode(i, ab);
    }

}
```

There is no need for scanner class in your code, you already have BufferedReader to read the file. Having both is redundant.

**toString() method override**

Add something like below method to your class.

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(EpisodeID + " & " +  Arrays.toString(Perek));
    }
```

Comment: I tried to replace the code to this one : I used @Kumar method and it worked but not exactly as I expected. Now the console print something, but it doesn't divide the text file right. I have to divide a book to 150 episode, so after every episode ends, I put the char $, but instead of dividing as I wish, it is printing this thing : TehilimEpisode@6bc7c054 TehilimEpisode@232204a1 TehilimEpisode@4aa298b7

Comment: Hi @AviatarS.  This is because toString method was not overridden in your TehilimEpisode class. Check my edit. If you are using eclipse, right click -> source-> override toString() Method.

Comment: I have done what you said but now I see that :
1 & [Ljava.lang.String;@232204a1

How can I convert that to the text itself?

Comment: This is because of string array is an object change Perek to Arrays.toString(Perek). This will print all entries in the array. Loop it as required.

Comment: Check my edit. Now it will print all entries in the string array. Use a loop to print them separately.

Comment: When I am trying to print the of the array, this is what I get :
"5 & [ $ ]"
I have tried to print system.out.println("pirkoni[5]"), and tried to write pirkoni.toString(); but neither of them is working.

Comment: Can you add your toString method in the question ?

Comment: Added, the question post has changed.

Comment: Thanks checking now.

Comment: hey, did you figure it out?

Comment: Hey @AviatarS. Sorry for delay.  I checked it, ur code is correct. Can you print the string array ab after splitting to the console? The same values in ab will be printed in the toString() method. Let me know the result.

Comment: @AviatarS. Did u checked?

Comment: this is my code now :
`while ((nextLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
     {
   ab = nextLine.split("$");
      for(int i=1; i<=ab.length;i++)
      {
          pirkoni[i] = new TehilimEpisode(i, ab);
          System.out.println(pirkoni[3]);
 }
}`
This is working, however, it just puts the whole book in the first place of the string array ab. 
This is my tostring method : 
`public String toString() {
    return String.format(EpisodeID + " & " + Arrays.toString(Perek));
}`
and when I try to print pirkoni[1] and further, it prints the episodeID and null 150 times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused here: `ab = scanner.nextLine().split("$"); pirkoni[i] = new TehilimEpisode(i, ab);`. Imagine there's no next line. It will try to create the TehilimEpisode object with `ab = null`. To fix this you should check if there's a next line:  `for(int i=1; i<=150 && scanner.hasNextLine() ;i++)`. Select as answer if It worked! :D

Comment: I tried to replace the code to this one : 
I used @Kumar method and it worked but not exactly as I expected.
Now the console print something, but it doesn't divide the text file right. I have to divide a book to 150 episode, so after every episode ends, I put the char `$`, but instead of dividing as I wish, it is printing this thing :
TehilimEpisode@6bc7c054
TehilimEpisode@232204a1
TehilimEpisode@4aa298b7

Comment: Override toString method in TehilimEpisode class and write after the return what you want to print in the System.out.println() function